# What are the rules for named arguments and why?

Tags: c#, syntax, language-design

Consider a method like this

```
void RegisterUser(string firstname, string lastname, int age);
```

I like explicitly naming the arguments of methods like this when I call them because it's easy for someone to mix up the `firstname` and `lastname` arguments.  However, it's not really necessary for `age`.  For instance, I would think this should be OK from a clarity standpoint.

```
RegisterUser(firstname: "John", lastname: "Smith", 25);
```

But the following error would be thrown:

> Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified

Another interesting thing is that if the signature were

```
void RegisterUser(int age, string firstname, string lastname);
```

then calling it as follows does NOT throw an error

```
RegisterUser(25, firstname: "John", lastname: "Smith");
```

Why is C# designed like this?  Is there a complication for the compiler if the first scenario were allowed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure even Python enforces this design. I'd say it's a good rule of thumb that if Python enforces something, it's probably very necessary. And ordering of arguments is very necessary.

Comment: @James yes, python enforces ordering, but in C# ordering the arguments is not necessary after you start naming them explicitly.  However, if you do enforce ordering when partial-naming of the arguments occurs then it would help make code more self-documenting and (imo) would make it easier to understand the code.

Comment: I am aware that you can begin naming arguments explicitly in both languages. Perhaps I phrased that poorly before. You can go from ordered arguments to explicit naming in the same function call, but you can't go back. It is the same between both languages.

Comment: Ah, yes, I understand.  Well the reason this is done in python is (in my understanding) because of the `*args, **kwargs` functionality.  In C# there is no such feature and thus I don't know of a reason why C# should be bound to not allow `RegisterUser(firstname: "John", lastname: "Smith", 25);`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the compiler might be able to figure it out but for us mere humans it would be nearly impossible to know if 25 refers to the 1st or 3rd parameter. Especially since it opens up the posibility of mixing arguments. why not

```
MyFunction(firstname: "josh", 25, "smith", someotherargument: 42)
```

How would you interpret this, 25 for age and smith for lastname? make a rule for it and a compiler can implement it. But what would make sense to humans. Code obfuscation shouldn't be that easy

A language should make it hard to make errors, not easier

NOTE: strange things start happening with the ordering if earlier arguments are named later. (like the firstname & smith in my example) because then becomes a puzzle for your unnamed arguments to be mapped to the right arguments. it could be done, but code shouldn't produce puzzles

Comment: So the idea, then, would be that naming some arguments and not others makes it easy to write hard-to-follow code?  In the code that I wrote, it almost is annoying to have to name the `age` argument.  Why dissallow it, especially if it's enforced that partial naming requires the arguments to be in order or something?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is appropriate as an edit to my question, but why would the following rule not be appropriate.  "in the event that an unnamed argument comes after a named argument, then the compiler will use order ONLY to resolve which argument is which".  This would remove ambiguity, and imo wouldn't make the code harder to read than if the few named arguments were unnamed.

Answer (score 7):

This is because when you name arguments the compiler maps it based on the names and ignores the function definition as long as all required arguments are present. In your case it doesn't know what 25 is. To us that seems logical that it has to be age, but if you change your example to:

```
void RegisterUser(string firstname, string lastname, int age = 0, int weight = 0);
```

and then say:

```
RegisterUser(firstname: "John", lastname: "Smith", 25);
```

Then the compiler doesn't know what to do with that last 25. This way of calling a function is mostly used in functions that has a lot of default values where you only want to set a few.

When not naming your arguments you're basically saying that you strictly follow the structure set by the function definition.

Comment: ah, this makes sense.  The rules change as soon as the compiler sees a named argument.  Before named arguments are found: order matters.  After: order no longer matters.  What if the rule were that if only some of the arguments were named, then unnamed arguments followed, that the arguments have to be in order?

Comment: That would be a mess and make the code way less readable. What if I did something like this:

RegisterUser(firstname: "John", "Smith", 25);

What would "Smith" be? The firstname?

Comment: To me, that's at least as clear as `RegisterUser("John", "Smith", 25)`.  Although, I do see where you're coming from.

Comment: It would also be slightly more difficult to debug as there could be confusion about which value is passed to which argument. The two ways separate makes this very clear, a mix of them will make it less obvious.

As for your example: That is clearer because you know the function definition and thus you know exactly which value is passed to which argument.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  My thought, though, is that clarity is the goal.  The function call `RegisterUser(firstname: "John", lastname: "Smith", 25);` to me is the most clear and concise (especially if there are more arguments after `age` which are equally unnecessary to label).  In that case, with more arguments it discourages me to go through my code and name appropriate arguments because of the overhead in naming 2, 3, 4 or more arguments as well (which may not be necessary for clarity).

Comment: a compiler could figure out just fine what to do with the 25, namely map it to the 1st not yet mapped argument (age in this case)

Comment: @Batavia It could if made to do so, yes, but it isn't so it doesn't.

Comment: but that is what the OP is asking, why couldn't a compiler do it.

Answer (score 6):

The intended use, with:

```
void M(int a = -1, int b = -1, int c = -1, int d = -1, int e = -1);
```

as an example, is that you can specify a subset of those optional parameters either by positional notation:

```
M(42, 28, 101);  // gives a, b, and c in order; omits d and e
```

or you can use named arguments:

```
M(d: 50, a: 42, c: 101);  // gives three arguments in arbitrary order
```

or you can combine them, where you start with positional arguments and then switch to naming arguments:

```
M(42, 28, e: 65537, d: 50);  // mixed notation OK
```

The reason for the restriction you have encountered, is that stuff like:

```
M(c: 101, 7, 9, b: 28, 666);  // ILLEGAL!
```

would be confusing.

I can see you propose to keep the positional ordering in your specific call, and then include names of some arguments only, for clarity. However, it appears that this use was not a priority for the language designers.

I suggest you name *all* arguments when your reason for using named style is clarity (as opposed to a need to specify a proper subset of the parameters only).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "it appears that this use was not a priority for the language designers." I think is wise. While this is what I wanted to use it for I never considered that it wasn't the actual reason that it was added as a feature.

Answer (score 1):

All named arguments have to come after positional arguments; you can’t switch between the styles.  Positional arguments always refer to the corresponding parameter in the method declaration.  You can’t make positional arguments skip a parameter by specifying it later with a named argument.  The compiler uses temporary local variables.  It then reorders those locals in the argument slots, my guess is that the compiler binds by arguments by order until it finds a named argument then it discards the arguments that it has already bound without names and reordered as the compiler uses temporary local variables.  The binds the rest by name, for instance it binds 25 with age then reordered firstname: "John", lastname: "Smith"

Answer (score 1):

Positional arguments are placed before named arguments. *Positional arguments always refer to the corresponding parameter in the method declaration*.

Suppose my method is:

```
void Dimensions(int height, int breadth , int length);
```

and i'm calling it like

```
Dimensions(3, length: 12, 24);
```

In this case:

> '3' is the first parameter and refers to height, but '24' is third parameter and refers to length, but we have already specified value of length.

So maybe to overcome this hindrance, by default c# style is to position **positional arguments** at start to provide correct referencing.

Also if we are defining optional parameters, providing positional parameters at end may lead to wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the language design in this case drives on the first named argument of any function.

Using your example

```
void RegisterUser(int age, string firstname, string lastname);
```

and calling it

```
RegisterUser(25, firstname: "John", lastname: "Smith");
```

Before encountering the first argument the compiler doesn't know whether this function is going to use any named arguments at all. Therefore it's a safe assumption for the compiler to do sequential mapping.

**25:**

The compiler gets the first argument and if it is a non named one then it will be mapped with the first argument from the function definition straight away.

**firstname:**

As soon as it encounters it's first named argument, things will change as the compiler will now have to check all the remaining arguments mentioned in the function definition to map the current named argument.

After it successfully maps it's first named argument the trail of sequential mapping has been broken. And therefore it's not feasible to provide a non named argument to compiler now as now it cannot establish where to map it.

If you think it should remember the last non named argument and start sequential mapping from there then that's error prone too as the named argument just defined might be sequentially right as well.

**lastname:**

And for the named arguments it's a breeze.

Hope this helps :)